# python format path-string to a list variables

Tags: python

Is any easy way to quickly initialize path format to list variables in python
Such as:

`dir = "/root/path/file"`

to

```
p[0] = "root"
p[1] = "path"
p[3] = "file"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
>>> dir="/root/path/file"
>>> p = filter(lambda x: x != '', dir.split('/'))
>>> print(p)
['root', 'path', 'file']
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine for the *exact* example posted, but will not work for something like `"path/subpath/file"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function for this:

```
p = dir.split('/')
```